# MSCRM Editing Email Templates in Customisation.xml did not update the template

Tags: dynamics-crm, email-templates

**What I am trying to do**

I am trying to remove the time section from the email template with a date field.

**What have I done**

I first tried to edit the template field in the template but could not edit the fields. I read I needed to go into the customisation.xml so I exported the solution, edited the line

```
/entity&gt;&lt;attribute&gt;piv_estimateddeliverydate/&lt;/attribute
```

to

```
/entity&gt;&lt;attribute&gt;piv_estimateddeliverydate/@date&lt;/attribute
```

I have reimported the solution, published the customisations (twice as I needed to double check it had been).

**What Is Happening**

When I create the email using the template the time part of the data is still visible

**What I want to happen**

I don't want the time section of the date included in the email.

**Other info**

The field is DateTime format Date only

Comment: You have the possibility to remove the time from date manually, incase if you are generating the email manually by user.

Comment: This is for a large business and we auto generate a lot of email. To manually remove on each email is not really an option. That's for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to open each of the templates and hit save. For some reason, this made the changes take place, even though they were imported into the solution and should have already been saved.

If someone can explain why we need to hit save on the email templates after importing the solution containing them, would be great.